# Vector.setSize and Vector.capacity returning different things

Tags: java, vector

I am trying to resize a Vector of ints but when I use `setSize`, it is setting the capacity of the `Vector` to something I'm not passing into `setSize`. I assume I'm not understanding something about the `setSize` function but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
System.out.printf("Capacity now: %d\n", timeline.capacity());
timeline.setSize(5);
System.out.printf("Capacity now: %d\n", timeline.capacity())
```

This bit of code returns:

```
Capacity now: 4
Capacity now: 8
```

If it matters, the original Vector of ints contains: 0111

Can a `Vector` size only be doubled?

EDIT: Ok, I set every `.capacity()` to `.size()` and everything is working smoothly. It worked perfectly with all `.capacity()` with a different test case so that problem had never even occurred to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're returning different things because they are different things :)

A Vector has both a *size*: the number of items in it, and a *capacity*: the length of its internal array that is used to store the items. The internal array length can be (and usually is) greater than the size, so that the array does not need to be reallocated so often when adding items. There are methods to set and get both these quantities:

- [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size--): returns the current size of the list (number of items).
- [setSize(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize-int-): truncates the list, or increases its size by adding `null` items.
- [capacity()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#capacity--): returns the current size of the internal array, which may be greater than the number of items in the list.
- [ensureCapacity(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity-int-): ensures the internal array has at least the specified length, but does not change the number of items in the list.
- [trimToSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#trimToSize--): trims the internal array so it is the same length as the number of items, so there is no wasted space.

P.S. Vector is obsolete since Java 1.2 (released in 1998), being replaced by [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Vector was designed in a time where it was thought to be a good idea for all such classes to be [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). It was later realized that that sort of blunt synchronization doesn't work too well and is rarely what is wanted, so the collections framework was re-designed, introducing the ArrayList class which has no synchronization by default, so is faster. It also has a slightly simpler interface.

Everything said about Vector above also applies to ArrayList, except for the setSize method, which ArrayList does not have, but the behavior of which you can mimic easily enough if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector`'s constructor is `public Vector(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement)` where `capacityIncrement` determines how large each capacity increment is. So a Vector's capacity can be tripled, quadruped, quintupled, et cetera as well.

But I think you are confusing a `Vector`'s size with its capacity. To use an analogy, the current balance of your bank account is its `size`; the absolute maximum amount of money your bank account can hold is its `capacity`. Unless you're Bill Gates, you won't need to care about what's the maximum limit of your bank account. Likewise, unless you have a very good reason (that's backed by micro-benchmarks) and know absolutely what you're doing, you don't need to manually manage the `capacity` of your `Vector`s, or any collections for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Vector can expand by any amount you specify. See the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector-int-int-)

Vector v = new Vector(4,1);